# How can i add current URL to .htaccess CSP header dynamically?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, shopify, shopify-app, litespeed

I'm currently working on Shopify app, one of their main requirement is to add an iframe-protection. [here is more info](https://shopify.dev/apps/store/security/iframe-protection)

Currently, to resolve this I need the CSP to set should be in this format :

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://shopify-dev.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com;`

The `https://shopify-dev.myshopify.com` in above code should be the merchant/ requester domain.

What I tried?
I created .htaccess file with following, it's not adding the dynamic url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
Header set Content-Security-Policy   "frame-ancestors '%{HTTP_HOST}' 'https://admin.shopify.com';"
</IfModule>
```

This is what I'm getting in console:

[image: Check here]

Answer (score 1):

#### Apache

On Apache, you would need to do it like this instead:

```
### Apache ###

Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://%{HTTP_HOST}e https://admin.shopify.com;"
```

Note the `e` after `%{HTTP_HOST}e` (specific syntax for mod_headers). I've also removed the single quotes (not present in the Spotify example) and included the `https://` protocol.

The `<IfModule>` and `RewriteEngine On` directives are irrelevant here.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header

---

**UPDATE:**

#### LiteSpeed

However, if you are using LiteSpeed (as opposed to Apache) you will instead need to first explicitly assign the `Host` header to an environment variable and use this in the `Header` directive instead. (Apache is able to access server variables directly using this syntax, but not LiteSpeed.)

For example:

```
### LiteSpeed ###

# Assign the "Host" header to an env var "HOSTNAME"
SetEnvIf Host "(.*)" HOSTNAME=$1

# Use "HOSTNAME" (env var) instead in the Header directive
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://%{HOSTNAME}e https://admin.shopify.com;"
```

Attempting to use the syntax `%{HTTP_HOST}` (as you originally had) on Apache would have resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error (with the error `"Unrecognized header format %"` being reported in the error logs). However, on LiteSpeed this just outputs the literal string `{HTTP_HOST}` and no error.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite for the reply but tits only printing https not the full domain , check the screenshot : https://ibb.co/1GLzXP8

i'm trying to find a solution since yesterday, still failing to solve this

Comment: @niyamxsept Ah, I've just noticed you are on LiteSpeed (from your screenshot), not "Apache" (as your question is tagged). On LiteSpeed, you'll first need to assign the `Host` header to an env var and use this instead in the `Header` directive. I've updated my answer.